# computer extremely slow. Generic Memory on 95-100% use. CPU is also high

Tags: windows-7, memory

No programs are running but my computer (HP G42, windows 7) is extremely slow even if I turn off Chrome and Dropbox . 
Here are the details about my memory usage.

[image]
[image]

Any idea why this happens and what I should do to fix this?

Comment: I think we would get a better idea if you gave us output of `tasklist` command entered in command prompt.

Comment: Hit `Show processes from all users` because the current process list is incomplete.  You have 87 processes running and only ~30 are shown in the screenshot.  Chrome and Dropbox are using basically nothing in terms of memory and cpu usage.

Comment: generic memory :http://i.stack.imgur.com/9VfU9.jpg

Comment: Here is the task list : http://imgur.com/a6FdjUR

Comment: take a screenshot of show processes for all users like ramhound said

Comment: You might want to check/stop a Windows Media Player service as explained here: http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/fix-wmpnetwk-exe-in-windows-7/  The process has allocated a lot of your memory.

Comment: Thank you guys.. I dont know how to show processes for all users but I turned off the Windows Media Player and every thing is faster now . In addition I found out that I had an "ClickPotato" program  on my computer.

Comment: @borisdesiatsky post your last comment as answer and mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys.. I dont know how to show processes for all users but I turned off the Windows Media Player and every thing is faster now . In addition I found out that I had an "ClickPotato" program on my computer.

Big thanks again to Ram Rahum, Ron Shabat, "Ashtray", "Axel Kemper" and all others helping me solve this problem.